# Where can I find a comprehensive list of NServiceBus configuration options and what they mean?

Tags: nservicebus

I'm having trouble locating documentation on the many NServiceBus configuration options for 
both the Code method and the Config File method.

I'm looking for a cohesive, comprehensive list and have searched in vain all over the product's on-line documentation.

Can anyone point me to that documentation if it exists?

Comment: Do you need anything else than http://particular.net/documentation/nservicebus ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little dated, but most of it still applies: [Customization Part I](http://adamfyles.blogspot.com/2011/03/nservicebus-customization-part-1.html) and [Customization Part II](http://adamfyles.blogspot.com/2011/04/nservicebus-customization-part-2.html)